# Which Algorithm should i use here? Finding Strings in a String Array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 2 Arrays.

One `Array` has Strings, which i look for.

```
static String[] namesToLookFor = { "NR", "STAFFELNR", "VONDATUM"};
```

the other`Array` has Strings, which i got from a *.csv file.

```
indexString = indexReader.readLine();
indexArray = indexString.split(";");
```

My Goal is to `system.out.println()`  the Values which are the `indexArray[]` and NOT in the `namesToLookFor[]`.

For example:

```
namesToLookFor = {"NR"};

indexArray = {"HELLO","NR"};


//Any Algorithm here...
```

So in this case`"HELLO"` should be printed out, since it is NOT in the `namesToLookFor[]` Array.

Comment: I'd suggest using a Set rather than an array, then you can difference the set objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over your `indexArray` and check for each element if its contained in your `namesToLookFor` Array:

```
    String[] namesToLookFor = {"NR"};

    String[] indexArray = {"HELLO","NR"};

    List<String> excludedNames = Arrays.asList(namesToLookFor);

    for(String s : indexArray) {
        if (!excludedNames.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Will output only "HELLO".

Comment: `Arrays.asList(namesToLookFor)` inside loop will create many unwanted objects. You should place it before loop and reuse

Answer (score 5):

If you are using java8 you can do the following

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(namesToLookFor);
Arrays.stream(indexArray)
        .filter(item -> !list.contains(item))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Put array into set for better performance
Set<String> namesToFilter = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("NR", "STAFFELNR"));
String[] indexArray = indexReader.readLine().split(";");

// Create list with unfiltered values and remove unwanted ones
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>(indexArray);
resultList.removeAll(namesToFilter);

// Do with result whatever you want
for (String s : resultList)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Array` you can use `contains` function but after converting it to be `ArrayList`, the `contains` function will check if the `ArrayList` contains a specific value.

```
for (int i =0; i<indexArray.length; i++) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(namesToLookFor).contains(indexArray[i])) 
            System.out.println(indexArray[i]);
    }
```